# Matrix non-identity

Tags: matrices

Let $M,N$ be $n\times n$ matrices. Then why is it that $MN-NM=I_n$ cannot be true, where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix?

I am thinking of perhaps there is an argument using determinants? (Of course I am probably way out.)

Thanks.

Comment: You weren't way out: Consider the trace instead of the determinant and remember that $\operatorname{tr}{AB} = \operatorname{tr}{BA}$.

Comment: And if you don't remember that fact about the trace, try to prove it.

Comment: asker: Since you are new to Math.SE, let me point out that you are explicitly permitted and encouraged in this site to answer your own question; so if you understood @t.b.'s comment, please consider posting your answer. That way, this post will appear as answered in the question, and other users will get a chance to upvote your solution.

Comment: You could note that $MN$ and $NM$ have the same eigenvalues, but $MN=NM+I_n$ would imply that the eigenvalues of $MN$ are all shifted by $1$ from those of $NM$.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @t.b.,

$\operatorname{tr}(AB-BA)=\operatorname{tr}(I)

\implies \operatorname{tr}(AB)-\operatorname{tr}(AB)=n$

Contradiction.

Comment: Good. For future reference, this argument won't work when you come to learn about matrices with entries in finite fields (or other fields of finite characteristic).

Comment: And at some point you can also accept this answer (and an answer to your other question) by clicking the tick on the left.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Interesting, would you mind illustrating?

Comment: @Rasmus: Thanks for the suggestion! I have tried doing that as you said but it keeps saying that there's an error...

Comment: Do you know about modular arithmetic? Working modulo 2 (for example), $1+1=0$, so the $2\times2$ identity matrix with entries taken from the integers mod 2 has trace zero. So in that setting, trace of $AB$ equals trace of $BA$ doesn't contradict $AB-BA=I$.